# Solving PDE in 3D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, spherical-harmonics

Could anyone solve below pde in 3d?
r is dposition vector in spherical coordinate.

> $$
> \nabla^{2}\mathrm{f} =
> \frac{a r^4}{1}\,\left[-1 + 3\left(\hat{e} \cdot \hat{r}\right)^{2}\right]
> $$

$\hat{e}$ is a defined vector in the x_y plane.

Comment: Find the Green's function in the appropriate coordinate system?

Comment: yes. That's the problem @KirylPesotski

Comment: How is $\hat{e}$ defined?

Comment: $\hat{e}$ is equal to (cos($\theta_0$), sin($\theta_0$),0). $\theta_0$ is a constant angle. @Dmoreno Could you please help me?

Comment: Do you have any boundary conditions?

Comment: f becomes zero as r tends to infinity @Dmoreno

Answer (score 1):

WLOG choose our coordinates such that $\hat{e} = \hat{z}$.  Using the fact that
$$
3 (\hat{e} \cdot \hat{r})^2 - 1 = 3 \cos^2 \theta - 1 = 2 P_2(\cos \theta),
$$
where $P_2(x)$ is the second-order Legendre polynomial, we guess a solution of the form
$$
f(r, \theta) = R(r) P_2(\cos \theta).
$$
Plugging this solution into the Laplacian, we get
$$
\nabla^2 f = \frac{P_2(\cos \theta)}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r^2 R'(r) \right) + \frac{R(r)}{r^2 \sin \theta} \frac{d}{d\theta} \left( \sin \theta \frac{d P_2(\cos \theta)}{d\theta} \right) \\
= \frac{P_2(u)}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r^2 R'(r) \right) + \frac{R(r)}{r^2 } \frac{d}{du} \left( (1- u^2) \frac{d P_2(u)}{du} \right) 
$$
where $u \equiv \cos \theta$. But by the definition of Legendre's equation, 
$$
\frac{d}{du} \left( (1- u^2) \frac{d P_n(u)}{du} \right) = - n(n+1) P_n(u),
$$
and so the original equation $\nabla^2 f= \frac{a}{r^4} (-1+ 3 (\hat{e} \cdot \hat{r})^2)$ becomes
$$
\frac{P_2(u)}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r^2 R'(r) \right) + \frac{R(r)}{r^2} \left(-6 P_2(u) \right) = \frac{2a}{r^4} P_2(u),
$$
or
$$
\frac{d}{dr} \left( r^2 R'(r) \right) - 6 R(r) = \frac{2a}{r^2}.
$$
This is a non-homogenous Euler equation and can be solved for $R(r)$ using standard techniques from ODEs.  One of the arbitrary coefficients in the resulting solution will vanish due to the demand that $f \to 0$ as $r \to \infty$.  Note, however, that no solutions exist such that $f \to 0$ as $r \to 0$ (regardless of the boundary conditions at infinity.)

Note that throughout this answer, I am using the "physics" convention for spherical coordinates where $\theta$ is the angle between the position vector and the $z$-axis, hence the need to pick $\hat{e} = \hat{z}$ above.  Once the overall solution for $f$ has been found, the coordinates in the solution can then be rotated such that $\hat{e}$ coincides with its original definition in the $xy$-plane (if desired.)

Comment: Thank youfor your nice answer. I have found general solution to the last equation, but I can not find particular solution :(

Comment: @OliverRange:  If you can't figure it out via guess-and-check, you can always use [variation of parameters;](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx) it's tedious, but it should work.

Comment: Do you have any guess for the particular solution?

Comment: why is "Note, however, that no solutions exist such that f→0f→0 as r→0" is correct?

Comment: @OliverRange:  The particular solution diverges as $r \to 0$, and the homogenous solution also diverges as $r \to 0$.  (And you can't combine them to get a finite solution as $r \to 0$.) Since this looks like a homework problem, I'd encourage you to try to work it out on your own from here.

Comment: You are right. Maybe the question was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\mathsf{I'll\ slightly\ modify\ the\ original\ post,\ as\ follows,}\
\mathsf{in\ order\ to\ discuss\ the\ convergence\ of\ radial}\
\\
\mathsf{integrals}}$:

> $\ds{\nabla^{2}\mathrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}} =
> {1 \over a^{3}}\pars{r \over a}^{\nu}\bracks{-1 + 3\pars{\hat{\mrm{e}}\cdot\hat{r}}^{2}} =
> -4\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2\pi a^{3}}\pars{r \over a}^{\nu}\,\,
> {3\cos^{2}\pars{\angle\pars{\hat{e},\hat{r}}} - 1 \over 2}}:\
> {\large ?}}$.

Note that
\begin{align}
&{3\cos^{2}\pars{\angle\pars{\hat{e},\hat{r}}} - 1 \over 2} =
\,\mrm{P}_{2}\pars{\cos\pars{\angle\pars{\hat{e},\hat{r}}}} =
{4\pi \over 5}
\sum_{m = -2}^{2}\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{r}}
\overline{\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{\mrm{e}}}}
\\[5mm]
&\mbox{such that}\
\nabla^{2}\mathrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}} = -4\pi\bracks{%
{1 \over 2\pi a^{3}}\pars{r \over a}^{\nu}\,{4 \pi \over 5}
\sum_{m = -2}^{2}\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{r}}
\overline{\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{\mrm{e}}}}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\,\mrm{P}_{\ell}}$ is a
[Legendre Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) and
$\ds{\,\mrm{Y}_{\ell m}}$ is a [Harmonic Spherical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics).
$\ds{\,\mrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}}}$ is given by
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}} & = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{{1 \over 2\pi a^{3}}\pars{r' \over a}^{\nu}\,{4 \pi \over 5}
\sum_{m = -2}^{2}\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{r}'}
\overline{\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{\mrm{e}}}}}
\,{\dd^{3}\vec{r}\,' \over \verts{\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'}}
\end{align}

> Hereafter, I'll use some properties which are explained in the above mentioned links.

Expanding $\ds{\verts{\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'}^{\,-1}}$ in Harmonic Spherical:
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}} & = {1 \over 2\pi a^{3}}\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{\pars{r' \over a}^{\nu}
{4\pi \over 5}\sum_{m = -2}^{2}\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{r}'}
\overline{\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{\mrm{e}}}}}\,\times
\\[3mm] & \phantom{=\,\,\,}\ \underbrace{%
\bracks{\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{m' = -\ell'}^{\ell'}{4\pi \over 2\ell' + 1}{r_{<}^{\ell'} \over r_{>}^{\ell' + 1}}\,\mrm{Y}_{\ell'm'}\pars{\hat{r}}
\overline{\,\mrm{Y}_{\ell'm'}\pars{\vec{r}\,'}}}}
_{\ds{=\ {1 \over \verts{\vec{r} - \vec{r}\,'}}}}\
\,\dd^{3}\vec{r}\,'\,,\qquad
\left\{\substack{\ds{r_{<} = \min\braces{r,r'}}\\[2mm]
                 \ds{r_{>} = \max\braces{r,r'}}}\right.
\\[1cm] & =
{1 \over 2\pi a^{3}}\,{4\pi\over 5}\sum_{m = -2}^{2}
\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{m' = -\ell'}^{\ell'}{4\pi \over 2\ell' + 1}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{r' \over a}^{\nu}{r_{<}^{\ell'} \over r_{>}^{\ell' + 1}}
\overline{\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{\mrm{e}}}}
\,\mrm{Y}_{\ell'm'}\pars{\hat{r}}\,\times
\\[3mm] & \phantom{=\,\,\,}\ \underbrace{%
\int_{\Omega_{\vec{r}\,'}}\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{r}\,'}
\overline{\,\mrm{Y}_{\ell'm'}\pars{\hat{r}\,'}}\,\dd\Omega_{\vec{r}\,'}}
_{\ds{\delta_{\ell' 2}\delta_{mm'}}}\
\,r'^{2}\,\dd r'
\\[1cm] & =
{2 \over a^{3}}\ \overbrace{\bracks{{4\pi \over 5}\sum_{m = -2}^{2}
\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{r}}\overline{\,\mrm{Y}_{2m}\pars{\hat{e}}}}}
^{\ds{3\cos^{2}\pars{\angle\pars{\hat{r},\hat{e}}} - 1 \over 2}}
{1 \over a^{\nu}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}r'^{\nu + 2}\,{r_{<}^{2} \over r_{>}^{3}}\,\dd r'
\\[5mm] & =
{3\cos^{2}\pars{\angle\pars{\hat{r},\hat{e}}} - 1 \over a}
\bracks{{1 \over a^{\nu + 2}}\int_{0}^{r}{r'^{\nu + 4} \over r^{3}}\,\dd r' +
{1 \over a^{\nu + 2}}\int_{r}^{\infty}r'^{\nu - 1}r^{2}\,\dd r'}
\end{align}

> Both integrals converge whenever
>   $\ds{\nu + 4 > -1\ \mbox{and}\ \nu < 0 \implies -5 < \nu < 0}$. Then,

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}} & =
{3\cos^{2}\pars{\angle\pars{\hat{r},\hat{e}}} - 1 \over a}
\bracks{{1 \over a^{\nu + 2}}\,{r^{\nu + 2} \over \nu + 5} -
{1 \over a^{\nu + 2}}\,{r^{\nu + 2} \over \nu}}
\\[5mm] & =\
\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{5\,{3\cos^{2}\pars{\angle\pars{\hat{r},\hat{e}}} - 1 \over a}
{\pars{r/a}^{\nu + 2} \over -\nu\pars{\nu + 5}}}}\,,\qquad \nu \in \pars{-5,0}
\end{align}